# Unity ShadeGraph Subgraphs and output position

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to create gernster waves in shadergraph, thus far I've got quite far and rather than having a huge complex mess id rather be neat about it and use the sub-graphs to improve readability and performance.

however, after inputting any variable into any sub-graph the output of the subgraph cannot be used to move the materials position.
such as this[image]

am i doing something wrong or is this just unity at play ?!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?  I'm stuck on the same issue.

Comment: Nope still waiting on an answer

Comment: I have the same problem, and sadly didn't find a solution either. It seems to just be a bug that still hasn't been fixed. Someone at Unity has acknowledged this though: https://forum.unity.com/threads/feedback-wanted-shader-graph.511960/page-19#post-3540057